# 'link rewrite' error in prestashop product add

Tags: xml, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have tried to add product in prestashop with the below data format.I am getting error 'link_rewrite is empty"]]>``'

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <product>
        <id_shop_default>1</id_shop_default>
        <name>
            <language id="1">BALERO 623-2RS</language>
        </name>
        <price>9.80</price>
        <reference>A-10273</reference>
        <description>BALERO 623-2RS</description>
        <active>1</active>
        <advanced_stock_management>1</advanced_stock_management>
        <id_tax_rules_group>1</id_tax_rules_group>
        <width>0.000000</width>
        <height>0.000000</height>
        <depth>0.000000</depth>
        <weight>0.000000</weight>
        <on_sale>0</on_sale>
        <online_only>0</online_only>
        <minimal_quantity>0</minimal_quantity>
        <customizable>0</customizable>
        <text_fields>0</text_fields>
        <uploadable_files>0</uploadable_files>
        <available_for_order>1</available_for_order>
        <condition>new</condition>
        <show_price>1</show_price>
        <date_add>2016-08-10</date_add>
        <associations>
            <categories>
                <id>2</id>
            </categories>
        </associations>
        <link_rewrite>
            <language id="1">BALERO</language>
        </link_rewrite>
    </product>
</prestashop>
```

Please give me suggestion why i am getting above error?

Thanks
Surajit

Comment: Are you using a module to import through XML?

Answer (score 0):

link_rewrite needs the variable already in the right format, so tiny and no spaces.

replace

```
<link_rewrite>
    <language id="1">BALERO</language>
</link_rewrite>
```

with:

```
<link_rewrite>
    <language id="1">balero</language>
</link_rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you edit product you have tab named "SEO", check field "Firendly URL".

If is empty fill this. And remember you must have enable friendly url in configuration Preferences -> SEO & URL's -> Set up URLs and set "Yes" for "Friendly URL"